# Refresh CURTIME() value in JQuery Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am learning to build a *PV Power Plant Monitoring Website*. My hardware feeding data to my SQL server per 10 seconds. Now, I have to represent those logged data in the form of gauge that refresh its value for every 10 seconds. But the problem is, I couldn't get my value to be refreshed by current time.

I am using mysql query `CURTIME()` to match computer time. But when I reapplied the query, `CURTIME()` doesn't refresh to actual current time. It's sticking to the last reading of `CURTIME()` when I load the page. So, `CURTIME()` refreshed only after I reload the page.

My question is, how to refresh the value of `CURTIME()` in the mysql query without needing to reload the page? Here is my script FYI:

```
<script>
  var g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6;
  var pvvol  = <?php include 'pvvol.php';?>;
  var pvcur  = <?php include 'pvcur.php';?>;
  var batvol = <?php include 'batvol.php';?>;
  var batcur = <?php include 'batcur.php';?>;
  var chgcur = <?php include 'chgcur.php';?>;
  var irrad  = <?php include 'irrad.php';?>;

  window.onload = function(){
    var g1 = new JustGage({
      id: "g1", 
      value: pvvol, 
      min: 0,
      max: 80,
      title: "PV Voltage",
      label: "Volt"
    });

    var g2 = new JustGage({
      id: "g2", 
      value: pvcur, 
      min: 0,
      max: 30,
      title: "PV Current",
      label: "Ampere"
    });

    var g3 = new JustGage({
      id: "g3", 
      value: chgcur, 
      min: 0,
      max: 80,
      title: "Charge Current",
      label: "Ampere"
    });

    var g4 = new JustGage({
      id: "g4", 
      value: batvol, 
      min: 0,
      max: 30,
      title: "Battery Voltage",
      label: "Volt"
    });

    var g5 = new JustGage({
      id: "g5", 
      value: batcur, 
      min: -50,
      max: 50,
      title: "Battery Current",
      label: "Ampere"
    });

    var g6 = new JustGage({
      id: "g6", 
      value: irrad, 
      min: 0,
      max: 1200,
      title: "Irradiance",
      label: "Watt / Sqm"
    });

    setInterval(function() {
      g1.refresh(pvvol);
      g2.refresh(pvcur);          
      g3.refresh(chgcur);
      g4.refresh(batvol);
      g5.refresh(batcur);
      g6.refresh(irrad);
    }, 2500);
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP code that is making the call to your database will only run once (every time the page is requested/refreshed). This means that the data from the database will never be updated, even though the JavaScript update code runs every 2.5 seconds.

You will need to use an [AJAX call](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to get the most up-to-date information from the database. Your JavaScript/jQuery code makes an AJAX call to a PHP file that returns the up-to-date information from the database. This information is then processed by your JS/jQuery and g1 to g6 can be refreshed with the new data.

## AJAX code example

**PHP code: getGaugeData.php**

This file is called by the AJAX request. It's job is to get data from the database and return it to the JavaScript code in a simple [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format.

***NOTE:*** I'm assuming that each of the included PHP files now creates PHP variables (`pvvol, pvcur, batvol, batcur, chgcur, irrad`) and assigns them values.

```
<?php
    /*
     * This PHP resource is only called via AJAX - it returns data in JSON format!
     */

    //Include PHP files that get the data
    //Each include file should define a PHP variable with the same name as the file: pvvol, pvcur, batvol, batcur, chgcur, irrad
    include 'pvvol.php';
    include 'pvcur.php';
    include 'batvol.php';
    include 'batcur.php';
    include 'chgcur.php';
    include 'irrad.php';

    //Create associative array of the data
    $data = array(
        'pvvol' => $pvvol,
        'pvcur' => $pvcur,
        'batvol' => $batvol,
        'batcur' => $batcur,
        'chgcur' => $chgcur,
        'irrad' => $irrad
    );

    //Convert the data into a JSON format string
    $output = json_encode($data);

    //Return the JSON data to the JS code
    echo $output;
    exit;
?>
```

**JavaScript code**

```
setInterval(function() {

    //Set up AJAX call to getGaugeData.php
    $.getJSON('getGaugeData.php').done(function(data) {

        //Use the AJAX data to refresh the gauges
        g1.refresh(data.pvvol);
        g2.refresh(data.pvcur);
        g3.refresh(data.chgcur);
        g4.refresh(data.batvol);
        g5.refresh(data.batcur);
        g6.refresh(data.irrad);

    });

}, 2500);
```

Comment: I consider your help to be useful. I found something when researching about AJAX Call on this [link](http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107).
But i couldn't get it work with my script. Can you give more clue on how to use it? Thanks

Comment: I'll put something together and will update my answer.

Comment: You are a big help! Now i just need to working out to merge this code to my website. Thanks mate!

Comment: No problem. You should just have to make some small changes to the include files and you'll be on your way.  :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get fresh data from your server without reloading the page I suggest that you look into ajax.

ajax is used to make calls to your server from javascript.